# Using java Runtime.getRuntime.exe() to open a folder give Super User credentials

Tags: java, linux, runtime, pi

I have a java application that opens a folder via

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("open /home/pi/data")
```

and it gives super user access when the folder opens. If I just run

```
open /home/pi/data
```

from the command line it gives normal access. I am not only interested in how to stop this from happening but also why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question. After realizing that the issue was not with the Runtime method but rather the open command itself. The open command originates from https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/ and seems to automatically invokes the sudo command when called from an external program. So the solution is to override the sudo with the non root user

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("sudo -u pi open /home/pi/data)
```

the -u command allows you to set the user, and pi is the default user on the RPi distro.